# Close popup on hardwarebutton backpressed in windows phone 8.1 application

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, popup

I have a popup that comes on a click event of button..
But I am unable to close the popup..I want to close popup on hardwarebutton_backpress event..
Can anyone plzz tell me how to do so..
I am using this code to show popup

```
Public void showpopup_click()
{
        Popup p =new Popup();
        p.child= new Mypopup();
        p.Isopen=true;
}
```

Here Mypopup is my user control..
I am using visual studio and developing a windows phone 8.1 app..

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to create the popup? Do you currently have any code doing anything with the back button right now?

You did not mention what language you are even coding in, so it's hard to give an answer.

Comment: I have frame.goback() code on my hardwarebutton back pressed event..

Comment: I have edited my question with needful details..plz answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach, in my opinion better, is using the `IsLightDismissEnabled` property where you don't need to check whether a popup is already open or not, or if you have multiple open popups, everything is handled automatically.

```
var popup = new Popup();
popup.IsLightDismissEnabled = true;
popup.IsOpen = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe to the `Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed` event to handle the back button with custom logic. If you store the Popup in a field, you can easily set IsOpen property to false.

Like this:

```
private Popup _popup;

public void showpopup_click()
{
    _popup = new Popup();
    _popup.Child = new Mypopup();
    _popup.IsOpen = true;

     Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
}

private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs args)
{
    _popup.IsOpen = false;

    args.Handled = true;

    Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
}
```

In the event handler, you need to set the args.Handled property to true to prevent the application close on the back button pressed. You also need to unsubcrise from the event to avoid memory leak.